# UV Unwrapping an .OBJ and pulling color from the model

Tags: uv, color, obj

I have an OBJ file that had a color heat map applied to it from another software suite. I am trying to UV unwrap the model and keep the color on the unwrapped image. Basically I want to create a 2D color image that corresponds to the color 3D model that I have. I have no problems creating a seam and actually performing the unwrapping step but I cannot for the life of me figure out how to apply the color to the unwrapped model. Thanks.

[image: Color OBJ Model]